# How I can remove extra symbols(\n, \t, \xa0) in stings(several conditions)?

Tags: python

While parsing data after I'm pasting strings in dict it shows these strings with **\n, \t \xa0**

I want to clean my internal strings, how I can do that?

I know I can use replace() but it has only one argument to exchange.I need several conditions to clean them.

Example:
'red': '\n\nJ. Rivera\xa0', 'blue': '\xa0I. Alcântara\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0'

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @aneroid yes you are right. OP must produce some efforts & show something that he may tried

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try to be more specific next time. And yes, I'll edit this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
dict1 = {'red': '\n\nJ. Rivera\xa0', 'blue': '\xa0I. Alcântara\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0'}

dict1  = {a:" ".join(b.split()) for a, b in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: I think join method is not handling "\xa0" which is space in string. output like {'red': 'J. Rivera', 'blue': 'I. Alcântara'} but after proper processing it should look like {'red': 'J. Rivera ', 'blue': ' I. Alcântara '}

Comment: @raviraj please check OP question above, He clearly indicated that he also wants to get rid of "\xa0"

Comment: @raviraj also FYI "\xa0" is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also known as chr(160). With relevance to standards a sentence or name never start or end with a space

Comment: you are right then.

Answer (score 0):

As I am able to see your string is having `\xa0` which is `unicode` value of `space " "`. So I would like to suggest below approach where you can see clear difference.

```
import unicodedata
import re

def normalize_string(given):
    regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')
    return re.sub(regex, "", unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", given))
    
dict1 = {'red': '\n\nJ. Rivera\xa0', 'blue': '\xa0I. Alcântara\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0'}
print("dict1 " ,dict1)
dict2  = {a:" ".join(b.split()) for a, b in dict1.items()}
print("dict2 " ,dict2)

dict3 = {k: normalize_string(v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
print("dict3 " ,dict3)
```

output is as follow

```
dict1  {'red': '\n\nJ. Rivera\xa0', 'blue': '\xa0I. Alcântara\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0'}
dict2  {'red': 'J. Rivera', 'blue': 'I. Alcântara'}
dict3  {'red': 'J. Rivera ', 'blue': ' I. Alcântara '}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple call to the strings [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method is all you need.

```
data = {'red': '\n\nJ. Rivera\xa0', 'blue': '\xa0I. Alcântara\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0'}
data = {k: v.strip() for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(data)
```

This will give you `{'red': 'J. Rivera', 'blue': 'I. Alcântara'}`.